# Permission denied - /tmp/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app that I've recently deployed to a remote server (Ubuntu 9.10, nginx, passenger, ruby-enterprise) and I'm getting the error (works fine locally):

> Permission denied - /var/www/project_name/tmp/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c

First, the folder /tmp/.ruby_inline/ is empty - should it be? Is it trying to create Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c or read it?

I think I have all the required gems installed: 'gem list' shows image_science and RubyInline installed. libfreeimage3 and libfreeimage-dev are also installed.

I've run chmod 755 on /tmp/.ruby_inline/ to match the permissions on surrounding folders but I cannot go any higher than that, however, or I get another error:

> /var/www/project_name/tmp/.ruby_inline is insecure (40777). It may not be group or world writable. Exiting.

And I guess second, why am I getting this error? :)

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be for serverfault more than for stackoverflow. I suggest you write it again there. Also, consider inscluding details about the servers: i.e. how is production different from local, and how did you set up production.

Comment: Thanks your probably right on both accounts - I was looking at it only from the dev perspective vs. admin. Hosting is with slicehost so it's not managed and I'm able to make any changes necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. The folder /tmp/.ruby_inline/ wasn't supposed to be empty so it wasn't finding Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c and giving a 'permission denied'. The files required were installed to ~/.ruby_inline so I just copied them to /tmp/.ruby_inline and chmod 755 them.

Answer (score 0):

also i guess the filesystem in the production is for some reason read-only to store static content. Contact your host.