# Getting Permission denied - /mnt/project-name/config/../tmp/ruby-inline/.ruby_inline

Tags: ruby, passenger, merb

I have made changes to my Merb application and deployed those to uat for testing but I am getting 
Permission denied - /mnt/project-name/config/../tmp/ruby-inline/.ruby_inline

I checked for the permissions in the path according to

[Permission denied - /tmp/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564779/permission-denied-tmp-ruby-inline-inline-imagescience-cdab-c)

But I couldn't able to solve it, so reverted back my changes and deployed old SHA which was running fine but I get same "permission denied Error" with the old SHA. 
I understood that the issue is not with the changes I made but with some other and I am not able to get whats going wrong and how to fix this. Please help me on this. Thanks.

- adding below the permissions on this path ...

  ls -l /mnt/project-name/config/../tmp/ruby-inline/.ruby_inline

  -rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 24571 2013-03-13 18:54 Inline_RawParseTree_ab80.c

  -rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 33465 2013-03-13 18:54 Inline_RawParseTree_ab80.so

  ls -l /mnt/project-name/config/../tmp/

  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 2013-03-13 18:54 pids -> /project-name/shared/pids

  -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      69 2013-03-13 18:55 restart.txt

  drwx------ 3 nobody nogroup 4096 2013-03-13 18:54 ruby-inline

  I don't get whats the issue and do cap deploy changes the file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission problem. The user that your application is running as is not allowed to write to /tmp/.ruby_inline. You need to either fix the permissions or ensure that the application is running as a user that has those permissions.